# Button is missing from dialog layout

Tags: android

Anyone know why my button isn't showing up in the dialog window?

```
    Dialog d = new Dialog(AddContact.this);

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup contentView = (ViewGroup) li.inflate(R.layout.dialog,null);

    d.setContentView(contentView);
    d.setTitle("Please correct these errors:");

    TextView error = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button closer = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    closer.setText("Close");
    error.setText(errorMessage);
    d.show();
```

This my dialog.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What do I need to do so my button shows in the dialog window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Please try below code

Only replace Textview in dialog.xml layout file:

```
<TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="5dp">**strong text**
<TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the button on my dialog and the cause ended up being that I was sending an **empty string** to setButton.